# Is there any native way to export and import PDF file inUWP?

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Is there any native solution for the exporting and importing PDF in UWP? Or do you have any suggestion to solve import&export PDF in UWP environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create and view PDF files from a UWP app then Syncfusion have a library for this
https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf

They also have a control for viewing PDF files too https://www.syncfusion.com/products/uwp/pdf-viewer

There is nothing built into the platform which includes support for working with PDF files in a UWP app.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but you mean there is not any built in class or library for the pdf import&export. Is that right? I should use third party library for this.

Comment: @MehmetÇopur yes. "There is nothing built into the platform" means you'll need to look to a 3rd party solution.